# How do I select each of these Elements with Jsoup?

Tags: java, dom, css-selectors, jsoup

I have this page that I would like to collect multiple values from:

[image]

I have tried multiple different slectors but I cant seem to get them to work and they return nothing,
I have found that this:

```
Elements eles = docWeather.select("rep:eq(0)");
String temp = eles.attr("f");
```

gets the first "f" value of 7 but I cant get the rest of the lines in the block like this:

[image]

UPDATE: I have also now tried using Phantomjs with WebDiver to select the elements and it returns a "No Such Element Exception"? The Xpath I used was:

```
WebElement weatherData = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapsible4']"));
```

Why am I unable to select this content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select all the `reps` of the first `period`.

Then iterate over the `Elements`.

Somethig like:

```
Elements eles = docWeather.select("location:eq(0) rep");
for (Element ele: select){
    String temp = eles.attr("f");
    System.out.println(temp );        
}
```

I Hope it helps

PS: Nice artworks :)

Comment: Hi, yes thanks thats what I had to do in the end but I am still wondering why I am unable to select it with any of the usual selectors. Thanks for the answer anyway.